# Customising error bars

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've been told I have to have custom error bars for an assignment I have to hand in.

Okay, I have a scatter graph with twelve points, and the error for each one is different. It's the same plus and minus, but different for each one.

The twelve different error values are sitting nicely in a column. I have been told I can reference that column in "custom error bars" simply by indicating the range of values, like F2-F14. However, I get an error message every time.

When I open Custom Error Bars, it is set up like this:

```
={}
```

obviously waiting for a function.

The error message says remove the equals sign. How should I enter the value range, please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your error values keyed in to a range (eg F2:F14) you can enter the range as:

```
=Sheet1!$F$2:$F$14
```

Alternatively, you could enter them here in an array:

```
={ value1, value2, value3,... }
```

(You are referring to Excel, right? I've tagged it as such.)